# Ubuntu 17.04: low screen resolution

Tags: screen, radeon, display-resolution

I have suffered a change in my screen resolution. I’ve just installed Ubuntu 17.04 (previously Windows), and my screen resolution decreased, and now only allow to select 1024x768 or 800x600 (see capture); I presume it may be a driver problem.

```
$ lspci
    ...
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) 2 port SATA IDE Controller #2
[01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. \[AMD/ATI\] RV620 LE \[Radeon HD 3450\][1]
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV620 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 3450/3470/3550/3570]
03:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): JMicron Technology Corp. IEEE 1394 Host Controller
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
05:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller (rev 02)
```

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to increase my screen resolution to previous levels.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you install the video driver for the AMD/ATI?

Comment: I've just installed Ubuntu 17.04, my screen run well during a couple of weeks but it changed to a lower resolution (I cannot imagine why). Reinstalled a completely fresh Ubuntu, but the problem persists.

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xrandr` to add custom resolution to the problem.
Typing `$ xrandr` on terminal will provide you some details about your current display.
`$ cvt 1024 768` if you want to add a resolution configuration for 1024x768.
which will give you an output something like this.

```
# 1024×768 59.92 Hz (CVT 0.79M3) hsync: 47.82 kHz; pclk: 63.50 MHz
Modeline "1024x768_60.00" 63.50 1024 1072 1176 1328 768 771 775 798 -hsync +vsync
```

Now create a new modeline

```
$ xrandr --newmode <Modeline>
```

Copy the modeline of the previous output to the place mode line

```
$ xrandr --newmode "1024x768_60.00"   63.50  1024 1072 1176 1328  768 771 775 798 -hsync +vsync
```

Now you need to add the above mode using the following command

```
$ xrandr --addmode VGA1 1024x768_60.00
```

here for VGA1 you have to use what ever that was there for $ xrandr output

```
$ xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1024x768_60.00
```

Now your resolution should be fixed but this will just long last for your current session. To make it work every time you login you need to create a bash file for it and then add it to startup app list.

Tell me if you need more help.

Comment: @Jordi did you try it?

Comment: Hi Ashvin, as you say it's only a workaround...but it works! Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You can initiate it on startup if anything doesn't work and you want to make thing permanent.